# Google Earth Engine Failed to decode JSON

Tags: google-earth-engine

```
var S2Collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(10,02,'month'));

var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int();
var cirrusBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();

function MaskS2Clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var S2CloudMasked = S2Collection.map(MaskS2Clouds);

function addNDVI(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI'));
}

var unfNDVI = S2CloudMasked.map(addNDVI).select(['NDVI']);

function filterNDVI(image){
  var masked = image.updateMask(image.gt(0.2));
  var mean = ee.Number(masked.reduceRegion({
      geometry: geometry,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  }).get('NDVI'));
  return image.addBands(masked.divide(mean.getInfo()).rename('stdNDVI'));
}

var fNDVI = unfNDVI.map(filterNDVI).select(['stdNDVI']);
```

My code fails on the last function. I want to divide each masked image by its mean (pixel by pixel) but I get:

> Failed to decode JSON.
>   Error: Field 'value' of object '{"type":"ArgumentRef","value":null}' is missing or null.
>   Object: {"type":"ArgumentRef","value":null}.

What is wrong?

Comment: Provide a link to your code or specify geometry. Do you have tested print(unfNDVI) to check if it contains an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is your goal, but I got the error. You cannot use the `.getInfo()` function, which basically is a client side function that sends a request to the server to retrieve it's content, inside a `map` function. But also, after correcting that, you'll have another issue: as you mask out many pixels using a 0.2 threshold, reducing over a `geometry` can return a `null` value (all pixels inside that geometry are null), so when you try to create an `Image` using that reduction (`mean` in your case) it will fail again. To overcome that error I used `ee.Algorithms.If` and created a zero image in that case.

```js
var S2Collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(10,02,'month'));

var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int();
var cirrusBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();

function MaskS2Clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var S2CloudMasked = S2Collection.map(MaskS2Clouds);

function addNDVI(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI'));
}

var unfNDVI = S2CloudMasked.map(addNDVI).select(['NDVI']);

function filterNDVI(image){
  var masked = image.updateMask(image.gt(0.2));
  var mean = ee.Number(masked.reduceRegion({
      geometry: geometry,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  }).get('NDVI'));
  var result = ee.Algorithms.If(mean, 
                                image.addBands(masked.divide(mean).rename('stdNDVI')),
                                image.addBands(ee.Image(0).rename('stdNDVI')))
  return ee.Image(result)
}

var fNDVI = unfNDVI.map(filterNDVI).select(['stdNDVI']);
print(fNDVI)
```

link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/2df2ff809ab970582d3ea8cad46b728c

Comment: Thanks!! That solved my problem